How can I set a parameter for a user's session?
I have an application that manages events for political campaigns. Volunteers can go to the site, view the upcoming events, and sign up for the events that interest them.
Campaigns would like to send volunteers to the site where it only shows their events. I have come up with the following approaches and am asking not for an opinion of these.

mydomain.com/CampaignName/events/marquee instead of mydomain.com/events/marquee.
mydomain.com/events/marquee?campaign=CampaignName and I then add that parameter to every link on every page.
Add a cookie campaign=CampaignName.
Set campaign=CampaignName in a session scoped service.

My question is, is there another approach to handling this issue?

See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=server - Protected Browser Storage if you want to preserve across SPA sessions.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis That's perfect for this - thanks. Please write as an answer for others that hit this question.

See this MS Docs article that describes all the main options - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/state-management?view=aspnetcore-8.0&pivots=server
Based on what you've said, Protected Browser Storage may be the best option if you want to preserve state across SPA sessions.
